# kafka-connect consumer fails with bootstrap broker disconnected

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have deployed kafka-connect cluster and have also did the right configuration for all connect properties but still my configuration fails to consume messages and fails with error.

```
bootstrap broker backbone.redpanda.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

my kafka-connect deployment looks as below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka-connect
  namespace: s3-connector
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-connect
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka-connect
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka-connect
          image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.1.9
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8083
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
          env:
            - name: CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
              value: "backbone.redpanda.svc.cluster.local:9092"
            - name: CONNECT_KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS
              value: "-Xms256M -Xmx2G"
            - name: CONNECT_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR
              value: "1"
            - name: CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR
              value: "1"
            - name: CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR
              value: "1"
#            - name: CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL
#              value: "DEBUG"
            - name: CONNECT_REST_PORT
              value: "8083"
            - name: CONNECT_GROUP_ID
              value: "kafka-connect-worker"
            - name: CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC
              value: "kafka-connect-configs"
            - name: CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC
              value: "kafka-connect-offsets"
            - name: CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC
              value: "kafka-connect-statuses"
            - name: CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
              value: "kafka-connect:8083"
            - name: CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER
              value: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
            - name: CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER
              value: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
            - name: CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH
              value: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/data/connect-jars"
            - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              value: "---"
            - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              value: "---"
            - name: CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS
              value: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
            - name: CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL
              value: SSL
            - name: CONNECT_SSL_ENABLED_PROTOCOLS
              value: "TLSv1.2"
            - name: CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION
              value: "/var/private/ssl/truststore.jks"
            - name: CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD
              value: "backbone"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: connect-config-props
              mountPath: /home/appuser
            - name: h2-bundle
              mountPath: /etc/tls-bundle
            - mountPath: /var/private/ssl
              name: tlscert
          command:
            - bash
            - -c
            - |
              echo "Installing Connector"
              confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3:10.4.0
              confluent-hub install --no-prompt mdrogalis/voluble:0.1.0
              #
              echo "Launching Kafka Connect worker"
              /etc/confluent/docker/run &
              #
              sleep infinity
      volumes:
        - name: connect-config-props
          configMap:
            name: connect-config
        - name: h2-bundle
          configMap:
            name: h2-bundle
        - name: truststore-thing
          configMap:
            name: client-cert
        - name: tlscert
          secret:
            defaultMode: 420
            items:
              - key: truststore.jks
                path: truststore.jks
            secretName: redpanda-client-cert
```

Properties config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: connect-config
  namespace: s3-connector
data:
  connect.properties: |-
    bootstrap.servers=backbone.redpanda.svc.cluster.local:9092
    connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
    tasks.max=1
    topics=demo
    s3.bucket.name=kafka-connect-s3-demo-devops
    s3.region=eu-west-1
    flush.size=3
    storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
    format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
    partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
    schema.compatibility=NONE
    security.protocol=SSL
    ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
    ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password=backbone
    consumer.bootstrap.servers=backbone.redpanda.svc.cluster.local:9092
    consumer.security.protocol=SSL
    consumer.ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/truststore.jks
    consumer.ssl.truststore.password=backbone
```

If I explicitely define the properties, it works but doesn't takes from the mounted properties.

Works fine:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server backbone.redpanda.svc.cluster.local:9092 --topic demo --from-beginning --consumer.config client.properties
```

Expected to work:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server backbone.redpanda.svc.cluster.local:9092 --topic demo --from-beginning
```

Same issue while connecting to s3 sink connector too:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Accept:application/json" \
    -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3/config \
    -d '
 {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "demo",
        "s3.region": "eu-west-1",
        "s3.bucket.name": "kafka-connect-s3-demo-devops",
        "flush.size": "1",
        "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
        "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
        "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
    }
'
```

Comment: If you want to deploy Kafka Connectors, I suggest you use Strimzi KafkaConnect operator, not your own Deployments

Comment: here I am using `confluent` kafka-connect image. Is that not wright ?

Comment: The image doesn't matter. I am telling you to use CRDs, not Deployment+ConfigMap https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/configuring.html#assembly-kafka-connect-str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connect.properties` doesn't do anything.

`CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` is the only thing that is affecting your error, and   if [`backbone` Service does not exist in the `redpanda`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) namespace, or that namespace does not have a NetworkPolicy to allow for connections from pods in the `s3-connector` namespace, then it will be unable to connect.

Comment: I understand but why the same works when I add it as a `config` within the command but not from `env` variables. My `client.properties` which I sent as a `--consumer-config` also has the same data as that of `env` variable.

`
printf 'security.protocol=SSL
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=backbone' > client.properties
`

Comment: If there is a problem with the connection to `broker`, can you please help me with the same ? I am pretty new to this.

Comment: I don't have access to your cluster, so I cannot help you debug network problems. Kafka Connect doesn't use `client.properties`, `consumer.properties` or `connect.properties`. The confluent image uses **`connect-distributed.properties`** and any environment variable will forcibly overwrite any ConfigMap/file that you mount.

Comment: sorry but thats why I am confused that why the image is not picking from `env` variables

Comment: It is, though. `value: backbone.redpanda.svc.cluster.local:9092` is the only entry being used, and nothing from your configmap is

Comment: thanks indeed got the answer and my issue was something different which got solved and I am able to connect to `AWS S3` too